# How can I re-normalize my git repo

Tags: git, line-endings, core.autocrlf

I have updated `core.autocrlf` option to be true (under Windows); now I want to re-normalize my git repository. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git rm --cached -r .
# Remove everything from the index.

git reset --hard
# Write both the index and working directory from git's database.

git add .
# Prepare to make a commit by staging all the files that will get normalized.
# This is your chance to inspect which files were never normalized. You should
# get lots of messages like: "warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in file."

git commit -m "Normalize line endings"
# Commit
```

Reference: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

Comment: Don't you need to push those changes to the remote repository?